# Guice / CDI / JEE6 Why does instance.select(qualifiers) use instances instead of Annotation of MyQualifier.class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, guice, cdi

Say you have this injection point:

```
@Inject
private Instance<DeliveryEndpoint> allEndpoints;
```

And you want to select a subgroup of endpoints annotated with `@ActiveEndpoint`

```
allActiveEndpoints.select(new AnnotationLiteral<ActiveEndpoint>(){})
```

Why on earth did the creators of CDI not just do this instead?

```
allActiveEndpoints.select(ActiveEndpoint.class)
```

That would have been a lot easier... I feel like because I don't understand this point, I'm likely going to do something wrong with my code eventually. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ActiveEndpoint is a simple qualifier - no parameters.  For qualifiers with parameters this wouldn't work.  Methods can only accept objects and qualifiers aren't objects.